# Mais de um valor em array para where Eloquent

Tags: laravel, postman

Estou desenvolvendo uma `route` para minha `api`, onde tem como finalidade retornar uma lista de cidades com base nos campos e valores de minha array. Dessa forma:

```
public function arrayCidades(Request $request)
{
    $ay      = $request->ay;
    return $ay;

    $result = Cidade::where($ay)->get();
    return $result;
}
```

Segue como estou passando pelo `postman`, e o retorno que ele me dá de primeira questão:

[image: postman]

Ao comentar a linha `return $ay;`, me retorna o seguinte erro `sql`:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined (SQL: select * from "cidades" where ("id_estado" = 15 and "nome_cidade" = 5))"

O meu objetivo aqui seria um sql assim:

```
select * from cidades where id_estado in(15,5) and nome_cidade = 'Santa Luzia'
```

Alguém sabe como resolver?

`Laravel 7.14.1`

Comment: Você está querendo passar os dados que vem no formato ARRAY ... ? isso tem que ser trabalhado no back-end, eu não entendi qual é o seu filtro, é por todos os campos ou é alguma em especifico.

Comment: Falta dizer o que você quer !

Comment: O nome do array sempre será por padrão `ay`. O nome dos seus campos será sempre algum nome que faça referência a tabela, como por exemplo `id_estado` e `nome_cidade`.

Comment: Não está entendível a sua duvida, porque quer fazer assim? Qual é o tipo de filtro que deseja fazer, acho que tenha uma forma melhor de conduzir esse filtro

Comment: Quais são os filtros? ou você quer algo dinâmico? explique melhor

Comment: Os filtros são os nomes dos campos do array, que fazem referência a campos da tabela

Comment: só que você tem duplicidade nos campos porque são arrays ... qual a finalidade?

Comment: Há a duplicidade pois quero passar mais de uma valor para o mesmo campo entende? Ao passar `ay[id_estado]` e `ay[id_estado]`, cada um pode assumir somente um valor, certo? Até aí ok, o meu controller retorna os dados e tranquilo. Porém se eu quiser informar mais de um estado diferente, com outro `id_estado` por exemplo, e usar isso na busco. Essa é minha dúvida: Se há como fazer dessa forma, porque pra mim já está meio caminho andado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diretamente como está no código não vai funcionar, tem que ter um lógica, um forma de analisar os parâmetros, exemplo no código abaixo foi analisado se o dado vem em um `array` simples e o outro se é um texto:

Layout dos dados a serem enviados:

```
{
    "id":[1,2,51], 
    "nome":"nome"
}
```

Código no back-end do Laravel:

```
$model = $this->model; // model do banco

$data = $request->all();
$keys = array_keys($data);        
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (gettype($data[$key]) === "array"){
        $model = $model->whereIn($key, $data[$key]);
    } else {
        $model = $model->where($key, $data[$key]);
    }
}
return $model->get();
```

ou seja, eu verifiquei se o dado é um `array` de uma dimensão se não acredito já ser um dado texto por isso do simples `if` e sempre atualizar o `model` com a última expressão do `builder` e por fim o resultado.

**Observação:** *Se tiver mais dados elaborados, precisa codificar um pouco mais para verificar tipos exclusivos da sua pesquisa.*

Comment: Era exatamente essa ideia que eu queria, obrigado!